# Read dynamic webpage html in either Python or R

Tags: python, r, selenium, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to automate the process of scraping the tables of webpages like  [Investing.com Economic Calendar](https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/) 
which is fairly straightforward with R if we are only interested in the default tab, which displays the calendar for today. Here is the R code:

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)

Econ_webpage <- read_html("https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/")

Indicators  <- Econ_webpage %>% html_nodes("#economicCalendarData") %>% 
html_table(fill = TRUE)  %>% .[[1]] %>% .[-(1:3),-  c(match("Imp.",colnames(.)),ncol(.))]
```

which produces the desired result displayed below.

```
> head(Indicators)
   Time Cur.                             Event Actual Forecast Previous 
4 19:50  JPY           BoJ Summary of Opinions                          
5 19:50  JPY              Exports (YoY)  (Feb)            1.9%    12.3% 
6 19:50  JPY              Imports (YoY)  (Feb)           17.1%     7.9% 
7 19:50  JPY              Trade Balance  (Feb)           -100B    -944B 
8 20:01  GBP Rightmove House Price Index (MoM)                     0.8% 
9 21:30  CNY         House Prices (YoY)  (Feb)                     5.0%
```

However, if I want to scrape the table in the tab Tomorrow I need to use the Selenium driver. I have tried RSelenium, but can not get it to work on my machine, so I have tried Selenium in Python. I use the following code in Python:

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver 

driver.Chrome(executable_path=PATH_TO_CHROMEDRIVER)
driver.get("https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/")
driver.find_element_by_id("timeFrame_tomorrow").click()
html = driver.page_source
```

Now I have the html containing the desired table data within a string, which I simply don't know how to efficiently pars to produce the result of the R code. Can I somehow call rpy2 package, which allows for R code within Python or someone else knows an easier way to extract the table in the same form as above? How do I parse this html string?

Comment: [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 2):

With `RSelenium` in `R` we could try

```
library(RSelenium)
library(XML)

rD <- rsDriver()
remDr <- rD[["client"]]
remDr$navigate("https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/")
option <- remDr$findElement("id", "timeFrame_tomorrow")
option$clickElement()
res <- readHTMLTable((remDr$getPageSource()[[1]]))$economicCalendarData
res <- res[-1,]
head(res)
#   Time Cur. Imp.                       Event Actual Forecast Previous 
#2 02:30  GBP      Investing.com GBP/USD Index                    46.5% 
#3 02:30  USD         Investing.com Gold Index                    65.6% 
#4 02:30  USD      Investing.com S&P 500 Index                    70.7% 
#5 02:30  CAD      Investing.com USD/CAD Index                    41.8% 
#6 02:30  CHF      Investing.com USD/CHF Index                    53.8% 
#7 02:30  AUD      Investing.com AUD/USD Index                    47.9% 


remDr$close()
rD[["server"]]$stop()
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, but as stated I couldn't start a driver client in R. I get the following error Selenium message:unknown error: unable to discover open pages
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.37.543627 (63642262d9fb93fb4ab52398be4286d844092a5e),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
   Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
  Further Details: run errorDetails method

Comment: I have searched for hours trying to fix the problem, as setting up Rselenium would tremendously help, but I get more and more obscure errors.

Comment: I get the same error. When I start Selenium in R, Chrome opens up, but then a popup Chrome Automation Tool crashed appears.

Comment: @user3612816  Could it be due to some version of chrome.  Try reinstalling chrome as well.  BTW, what is your R version and the package versions?

Comment: R version 3.4.3 Patched (2018-02-11 r74250)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1                     Chrome version: Version 65.0.3325.162

Comment: I solved the problem in Python using Beautifulsoup and pandas. All is needed is to call dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source), once one navigates to the right website.

Comment: @user3612816  I am using `R version 3.4.3` on `Windows 10 x64 (build 15063)` with `RSelenium_1.7.1`, Chrome version `Version 64.0.3282`

Comment: @user3612816  I think the function names are also similar